# Cannot run gradlew.bat from project sub folder

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

I have below project struture

```
MyProject
    projA
    projB
        build.gradle
gradlew.bat
build.gradle
gradlew
settings.gradle
```

I have below task in `MyProject/projB/build.gradle`

```
def process;
task bootRunStartDaemon() {
    doFirst {

        println("Starting application it profile")

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("./gradlew.bat", "bootRun", "--args='--spring.profiles.active=it'")
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true)
        builder.directory(projectDir)
        process = builder.start()

    }
}
```

However when I run `> gradlew bootRunStartDaemon` from the root directory I get below error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./gradlew.bat" (in directory "MyProject\projB"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:62)
```

I have below in `settings.gradle`

```
....
rootProject.name = "MyProject"
include "projA", "projB"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mamaged to run gradlew.bat by adding the path as below. Because gradlew.bat scripts only exists under the root folder.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(projectDir.toString().replace("projB","")  + gradleCommand, "bootRun", "--args='--spring.profiles.active=it'")
```